# Sometimes search view is not working properly in listview

Tags: android

I am having hotel menu items in listview.before dat listview i'm having edittext with search function.I have to search hotel items by item name and area.it's working fine.but sometimes while searching by area it doesn't show anything.if I reopen that app and searching means it's working properly.I dont know where the mistake happened.pls help me....

Search code

```
       mSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String text = mSearch.getText().toString().toLowerCase();

         arrayTemplist= new ArrayList<HotelItem>();


            for (int i = 0; i < searchItems.size(); i++)


            {
  //                     String currentString =hotelItems.get(i).getArea();
  //                     String currentString1 =hotelItems.get(i).getName();

  //                    String presentString=     (currentString+currentString1).toLowerCase();
                  String currentString =searchItems.get(i).getName();
                  String currentStringg =searchItems.get(i).getArea();

                  String presentString=currentString.toLowerCase();
                  String presentString1=currentStringg.toLowerCase();

                //if (text.equalsIgnoreCase(currentString))

                if(presentString.contains(text))
                {
                    arrayTemplist.add(searchItems.get(i));
                }

                if(presentString1.contains(text))
                {
                    arrayTemplist.add(searchItems.get(i));
                }
            }


               searchAdapter = new HotelsSearchAdapter(HotelsActivity.this,           arrayTemplist);

                listView.setAdapter(searchAdapter);



    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});




    //code for listview item selection 

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String search =mSearch.getText().toString();

            if(search.isEmpty()==true){
            String SelectedId = hotelItems.get(position).getId();

           //                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "HotelId"+SelectedId,    3000).show();
                System.out.println("hotel id ..........."+SelectedId);
                String SelectedHotel = hotelItems.get(position).getName();
                String Area =hotelItems.get(position).getArea();


              Intent id1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    MainActivity.class);
            id1.putExtra("selectedId", SelectedId);
            id1.putExtra("selectedHotel", SelectedHotel);


            startActivity(id1);
            }


            if(search.isEmpty()!=true){

                String SearchedId = arrayTemplist.get(position).getId();

                String SelectedHotel = arrayTemplist.get(position).getName();
                String Area =arrayTemplist.get(position).getArea();


                Intent id1 = new Intent(HotelsActivity.this,
                        MainActivity.class);
                id1.putExtra("selectedId", SearchedId);
                id1.putExtra("selectedHotel", SelectedHotel);
                id1.putExtra("area", Area);

                startActivity(id1);

            }

        }
    });
```

//      to clear the search text

```
    btnSearch.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            mSearch.setText(" ");

        }
    });
```